# JS heap rises gradually and then falls. Is this a memory leak?

Tags: memory-leaks

I'm working on an app with a lot of code that is black box to me. While debugging something else I noticed that if you switch back and forth between tabs the old tabs r
g

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the part about tab switching, but in general a healthy heap will look exactly like the graph you posted. The concern would be if it did not return to (near) the baseline after GC. Background info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

Comment: Okay thanks. I also just realized by referencing the object on window I was guaranteeing that it didn't get garbage collected unless someone explicitly called delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, anything on root scope won't be GC'd:

> *Mark-and-sweep algorithm*
>
> This algorithm reduces the definition of "an object is not needed anymore" to "an object is unreachable".
>
> This algorithm assumes the knowledge of a set of objects called roots (In JavaScript,
>   the root is the global object). Periodically, the garbage-collector
>   will start from these roots, find all objects that are referenced from
>   these roots, then all objects referenced from these, etc. Starting
>   from the roots, the garbage collector will thus find all reachable
>   objects and collect all non-reachable objects.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

In general a healthy heap will look exactly like the graph you posted. The concern would be if it did not return to (in a pragmatic world: near) the baseline after GC.